# How can I optimize flatMap Operator in Webflux?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm developing an API that can store multiple music at once. This request can have a mix of Music from different types of Albums. I also assumed a scenario that might contain multiple Music from the same album.

I want to merge `MusicInput` and Album and convert it into `Music` Document class. `Music` Document has the `id` and `name` of `Album` (because of De-Normalization), so I have to send a query for Album.

`MusicInput` is a DTO for receiving input from users and contains albumId.
`MusicInput` has the `toEntity()` method.

```
fun toEntity(album: Album) = Music(
    name = name,
    releaseDate = releaseDate,
    genre = genre,
    album = album
)
```

I think it's a better way to ask for all album documentation with one query because I thought it was a better way to ask for it at once rather than generate a query multiple times to query the album.

After that, I want to merge the requested MusicInput and Album classes to create a Flux  instance.
I implemented the code like this.

```
val groupedMusic = musicInput.groupBy(MusicInput::albumId)

return albumService.findAllByIds(groupedMusic.map(GroupedFlux<String, MusicInput>::key))
    .collectMap(Album::id, Function.identity())
    .flatMapMany { albumMap ->
        musicInput.map { musicInput ->
            val album = albumMap.getValue(musicInput.id)
            musicInput.toEntity(album)
        }
    }
```

But this is falling into a callback hell and I'm not even sure if it works asynchronously well.
What would be a better way?

Comment: Why do you call this a callback hell? This is normal functional paradigm to me. Two lambda does not look that annoying to me, especially since you need to access `albumMap` in the `musicInput.map` operator. You could try to flatten this into a record but it seems like a huge overhead to me.

Comment: @VincentC. I might have been too obsessive about overlapping flatmaps or maps. But I wanted to get an opinion if there was a better way. Thanks for the comments!